# Protractor - how to check that an element contains text

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a button which has a text. I would like to assert that the button contains text, but I don't want to check the text because the same button in a different page can have other text, and to make it dynamically, I would like to check only that it has text.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the text length, eg

```
element.getText().then(function(text) {
    expect(text.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);

    // or maybe...
    expect(text).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `toBeNonEmptyString()` matcher from [`jasmine-matchers`](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers), one line:

```
expect(elm.getText()).toBeNonEmptyString();
```